# React render: Objects are not valid as a React child when rendering data from firebase

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render some data from a firebase db but i'm getting this error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

Here's my code:

Index.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from '../../components/Navbar/Navbar';
import EventoCard from '../../components/evento-card/EventoCard';
import firebase from '../../config/firebase';
import './home.css';

const Home = () => {

    const [eventos, setEventos] = useState([]);
    //recuperando o banco;
    const db = firebase.firestore();
    let listaEventos = [];
    useEffect(() => {
        db.collection('eventos').get().then(async (resultado) => {
            await resultado.docs.forEach(doc => {
                listaEventos.push({
                    id: doc.id,
                    ...doc.data()
                })
            })
            setEventos(listaEventos);
        })
    })

    return (
        <>
            <Navbar></Navbar>
            <br></br>
            <div className="row">
                {eventos.map(item => <EventoCard key={item.id} titulo={item.titulo} detalhes={item.detalhes} />)}
            </div>

        </>
    );
}

export default Home;
```

EventoCard.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import './evento-card.css';

const EventoCard = (key, titulo, detalhes) => {
    return (
        <div className="col-md-3 col-sm-12">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150x100" className="card-img-top imgCartao" alt="Imagem Do Evento" />
            <div className="card-body">
                <h5>{titulo}</h5>
                <p className="card-text text-justify">{detalhes}</p>
                <div className="row rodape-card d-flex align-itens-center">
                    <div className="col-6">
                        <Link to='/' className="btn btn-sm btn-detalhes">+ Detalhes</Link>
                    </div>
                    <div className="col-6 text-right">
                        <i className="fas fa-eye"></i><span>12312</span>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default EventoCard;
```

And my json objects are defined as title and details basicaly. I thought that something was wrong with the map function but i don't know what i am missing here.

Comment: Log the data that you're receiving and make sure it's structured the way you think it is. I'm almost certain that ```titulo``` or ```detalhes``` is causing this because, like the error says you are trying to render an object instead of a string/number.

Comment: They are JSON objects:

id: "f7tlrOXin85gkgtPxx6v"
criacao: Timestamp {seconds: 1578511909, nanoseconds: 165000000}
data: "2020-01-15"
detalhes: "Evento teste 2"
hora: "01:00"
imagem: "Samsung A207G.jpg"
publico: 1
tipo: "Festa"
titulo: "Evento teste 2"
usuario: "jvam90@gmail.com"
visualizacoes: 0

What i'm trying to print is 'detalhes' and 'titulo'

Comment: Make sure detalhes is what you expect because the problem may be here <p className="card-text text-justify">{detalhes}</p>

Comment: They are all strings. i did console.log the objects and they appear as strings, and not objects.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what was wrong:

```
const EventoCard = ({ key, titulo, detalhes }) => {
```

I had to put the parameters between curly braces.